# Can Keras' Sequential fit() function take as train data a Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I want to create a neural network with Keras and my training data is in a pandas data frame, called df_train, which has the following form. Every row is an event/observation consisting of 51 variables.

```
df_train.head()
```

[image]

My question is, can I use this df_train data frame as an input in the Keras model.fit() command? As following

```
net = Sequential()
net.add(Dense(70, input_dim = 51, activation = "relu"))
net.add(Dense(70, activation = "relu"))
net.add(Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")) 
net.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics = ["accuracy"])
net.fit(df_train, train_labels, epochs = 300, batch_size = 100)
```

In the net.fit() I pass as train data a data frame, but in sequential documentation it doesnt mention a data frame as a valid input. However, in my code it works and the model runs normally. Is something happening wrong behind the backstage and simply there is no error, or it is running as intended even when you use a pandas data frame as input?

Also, if it works, does the fit() command in this case take as input one row of the given data frame a t the time?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please don't share code/data as images. This might be useful to you: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe.

Comment: _Is something happening wrong behind the backstage and simply there is no error, or it is running as intended even when you use a pandas data frame as input?_ The latter. If you read the docs for `Sequential.fit()`, you'll see that the description for the `x` argument mentions _A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs)_ and _A dict mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, if the model has named inputs_. My guess is that a Pandas DataFrame behaves like one of those two.

Comment: I read the documentation and saw the exact things you said. Maybe it behaves as a dict but since it doesnt specifically mention Pandas objects, I cant know for sure!

Answer (score 1):

```
net.fit(df_train, train_labels, epochs = 300, batch_size = 100)
```

In this df_train   is 2D  and   train_label can be 2D or 1D (it depend upon loss which you mention and units of output layers)

2nd question answer : Yes you can do

If you want to input X as single row which is 1D then it generated error:

```
 ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:array=[1. 2. 3. 4.].
 Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature 
 or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

**How we resolve this one**

converted into 2d !

```
 X=train.iloc[0:1,:]
 print(X.shape)
 output:(1, 25)
 # now this single row converted into  two dim:
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me elaborate a bit more. Regarding my first question, what I wanted to know was if keras' fit(), the one you posted, can take a pandas DataFrame object as input, instead of a numpy array object. About the second one, what I wanted to know was: when you run the fit(train_data, labels), the neural network is taking automatically as input every time it runs, the rows of the train_data? Or can I change it to be the columns. Hope you can help a bit on those things i posted here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a specialized method, called `flow_from_dataframe`. Similar to `flow_from_directory` which reads and feeds images to your neural network, the former method allows you to feed data from a dataframe.

You can have a look here in order to see an application of `flow_from_dataframe`:

https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-flow-from-dataframe-1fd4493d237c

The second option is to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`, which is specific to TensorFlow specialized data pipeline.

An example of it is available here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_csv_data

The third method and perhaps in the future the most elegant and fast from a performance view `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset`. The reason that I am saying in the foreseeable future is that, as you can see, it is part of the 'experimental' packages; that means it is something new and thus not mature and stable enough. A link about it is provided here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset

You can try either of these methods, but for beginning, I would stick to `flow_from_dataframe`.